# Force Java to Scala explicit type casting on unknown java.util.Map type

Tags: java, scala, casting, type-conversion, scala-collections

I recently worked with some Java collection (well know JavaFX), and I had recently a problem (a consequence of this other problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100594/javafx2-and-setcellvaluefactory-with-mapvaluefactory-filling-method-in-scala)). One of the JavaFX interfaces I need only accepts `java.util.Map`, equal to `Map[_,_]` in Scala.

I make a conversion with `asInstanceOf`, but after computation, if I want to transform my `java.util.Map[_,_]` to force the cast into a real Scala type safe `Map[String,Double]` I use in all my program, how can I do it?

I tried `java.conversions._` and `asInstanceOf` methods without success.

```
//return a java.util.Map 
val row: java.util.Map[_,_] = c.getTableView().getItems().get(0)
//I need a Map[String,Double] in my program
val parameters = row.toMap[String,Double]
```

Comment: Does `import collection.JavaConverters; row.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String,Double]].asScala` work?

Comment: import collection.JavaConverters._, isn't @LuigiPlinge?

Comment: I have a type mismatch, but it seems it's a start of solution !
`found   : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Double]
required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]`

Comment: if i add a `toMap` instruction like this,  `row.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String,Double]].asScala.toMap`, it work, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me

```
val javaMap : java.util.Map[_, _] = null
val scalaMap = javaMap.asScala.toMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Double]]
```

Remember to include

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

Answer (score 1):

@monkjack's code compiles, but it gives me a runtime exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$JMapWrapper cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

My fix was to use [toMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions%24.html):

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

...

val scalaMap = javaMap.toMap.asInstanceOf[String, Double]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will solve your problems:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

import scala.collection.immutable.Map

class Utility {

 def toScalaMap(javaMap: java.util.Map[String, Object]): Map[String, String] = {
   return javaMap.toMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
 }
}
```